# proof of Laurents extension theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I found this theorem of Laurents expansion theorem online, but there is one thing I do not understand. How can he just say that $\gamma$ is a union of two cicles? Does he make some kind of toy-contour? And this toy contour uses some kind of trick so that it has both $\gamma$ and two circles? Could you explain how this looks?, maybe draw if you have the time? And does it still work if the point z is on $\gamma$? And does he explain why it holds for any r?

[image]

EDIT: suggested new proof:

Let z be in the annulus.

Using cauchys integral theorem on gamma1, and gamma 2 in the picture, and letting the gate between them go to zero we get that:

[image]

$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$

On $\gamma_1$, we ahve that $\frac{1}{w-z}=\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(z-a)^k}{(w-a)^{k+1}}$, and on $\gamma_2$, we have $\frac{-1}{w-z}=\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(w-a)^k}{(z-a)^{k+1}}$. If we put this in in the above expression we get.

$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_1}\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{k+1}}(z-a)^kdw+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_2}\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{-k}}*(z-a)^{-k-1}dw$

$=f(z)=\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{k+1}}dw(z-a)^k+\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{-k}}dw(z-a)^{-k-1}$.

The integrals $\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{k+1}}dw$ and $\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{-k}}dw$, do not depend on on the circles they are integrated around because the are holomorphic in the entire annulus, so we may integrate both of them around a circle with radi r(cauchys theorem), this circle with radi r **may** intersect z.

Hence we get:

$f(z)=\Sigma_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_r\frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{k+1}}dw(z-a)^k$

Answer (score 2):

> How can he just say that $\gamma$ is a union of two circles?

That's how $\gamma$ is chosen. That choice is made because it is convenient, of course. One could take wobbly paths, but that would not be as nice for the expansion of $\frac{1}{w-z}$ into a geometric series.

To apply Cauchy's integral formula, you need a contour in $\Omega$ that winds once around $z$, and not around any point in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega$. If you take a circle $C_\rho$ (traversed counterclockwise) with centre $a$ and radius $\lvert z-a\rvert < \rho < r$, then you have a path winding once around $z$. But that path also winds once around $a$, and that has to be cancelled. And that winding around $a$ is cancelled by taking a further circle $C_s$ - this time traversed clockwise - with centre $a$ and radius $0 < \sigma < \lvert z-a\rvert$. Since the small circle doesn't wind around $z$, and neither circle winds around any point of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega$ except $a$, the contour $\gamma = C_\rho + C_s$ is a nullhomologous cycle in $\Omega$ winding once around $z$, and hence Cauchy's integral formula says

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw.$$

> Could you explain how this looks?

Two concentric circles, the larger traversed counterclockwise, and the smaller traversed clockwise, with the point $z$ lying between the two circles. These two circles form the boundary of an annulus containing $z$ - and thus the choice of the radii of the two circles depends on $z$, but, given $z$, any choice of the two radii satisfying the condition

$$0 < \sigma < \lvert z-a\rvert < \rho < r$$

works. Since the integrand $\frac{f(w)}{w-z}$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the closed annulus $\{ w : \sigma_1 \leqslant \lvert w-a\rvert \leqslant \sigma_2\}$ for all $0 < \sigma_1 < \sigma_2 < \lvert z-a\rvert$, Cauchy's integral theorem asserts that the integral

$$\int_{C_\sigma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw$$

is independent of $\sigma$ subject to the constraint $0 < \sigma < \lvert z-a\rvert$. The analogous argument shows that the integral over $C_\rho$ is independent of $\rho$, as long as that satisfies the above condition.

> And does it still work if the point $z$ is on $\gamma$?

No. If $\gamma$ passes through $z$, the integrand has a non-integrable pole on the contour - except if $f(z) = 0$ - and thus the integral does not exist then. But, for every $z$, we can choose appropriate radii, and as mentioned above, the choice of radii is immaterial (as long as the conditions are satisfied). And for any fixed $0 < \sigma < \rho < r$, the integral formula, and the expansion of $\frac{1}{w-z}$ into geometric series hold for *all* $z$ with $\sigma < \lvert z-a\rvert < \rho$.

Comment: Thanks, I've read through it a number of times now, but there is stills omething I do not understand. You say that the integral over the small circle is independent of which circle we choose aslong as it is small enough? But doesnt the curve then have to be a toy contour or in a simple connected set? In our set there is a hole in the middle, so the set isn't simply connected? And is it so that the two radius are interchanged with one radius r in the end?, how do we get that?

Comment: What do you mean by "toy contour"? We don't need a simply connected set. Cauchy's integral theorem says that if $g \colon U\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, then $\int_\alpha g(z)\,dz = \int_\beta g(z)\,dz$ for all cycles $\alpha,\beta$ in $U$ that are homologous in $U$ [$\alpha \sim_U \beta$ means $n(\alpha,w) = n(\beta,w)$ for all $w\in \mathbb{C}\setminus U$]. The function $w \mapsto \frac{f(w)}{w-z}$ is holomorphic in $U = \Omega\setminus \{z\}$, and the conditions imposed ensure that the cycles $C_{\sigma_1}$ and $C_{\sigma_2}$ are homologous in $U$.

Comment: The analogous holds for the large circles, of course. I don't quite get what you mean by "And is it so that the two radius are interchanged with one radius r in the end?". Are you referring to the integral formula $$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}}\,dw\,?$$ That that integral is independent of the radius of the used circle again follows from the integral theorem (since all circles with centre $a$ [and radius $0 < \rho < r$, so that they lie in $\Omega$] are homologous in $\Omega$). You get the formula by expanding $f(w)$ into its Laurent series, which was derived using

Comment: the two circles and the integral formula.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what an homology is, I have just learned this version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem, but I think I see why it holds using another argument. A toy contour is just a nice closed curve with a well defined interior. But the point is that for the proof you use curves that do not intersect the point z, but in doing this you get integrals which are independent of radi, and you can change with a radi that might have intersected z anyway?

Comment: The wikipedia article mentions the more general version (but with different terminology, what I call cycle, they call "closed chain", and what they call "cycle", I call "nullhomologous cycle") directly after the statement of the restricted version. Regarding " but in doing this you get integrals which are independent of radi, and you can change with a radi that might have itnersected z anyhow?", you missed that the conditions imposed on $\sigma$ and $\rho$ are precisely to ensure that changing the radii does _not_ move either circle through the point $z$, since that [besides $a$] is the point

Comment: Can we say that the point of the proof is that you start with integrals involving 1/(w-z), which makes the function not holomorphic, but you end up with only having to evalute integrals involving 1/(w-a) which are holomorphic, and in these integrals the radi can be z?

Comment: we must avoid. If we take a concrete example, say $\Omega = \{z : 0 < \lvert z\rvert < 2\}$, and choose the point $z = 1$, then we can take pairs of circles with radii $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$, or with radii $\frac{1}{123}$ and $\frac{511}{256}$, or any pair $(\sigma,\rho)$, as long as $0 < \sigma < 1 < \rho < 2$. The integral over the smaller circle is independent of the radius as long as $0 < \sigma < 1$, and the integral over the larger circle is independent of the radius as long as $1 < \rho < 2$.

Comment: I still dont quite understand what you mean. But can't we say that even though we start with integgrals involving 1/(w-z), when we put in the power/geometric series representation, we only are interested in integrating 1/(w-a), or a power of this, and this function is holomorpic in the entire annulus. Is this another valid explanation?, sorry I just can't wrap my head around what you mean.

Comment: Not really, and yet yes. The $\frac{1}{w-z}$ and $\frac{1}{w-a}$ are different parts of the proof in a way. We use two circles and $\frac{1}{w-z}$ to obtain the Laurent series representation $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n (z-a)^n.$$ From the way one proceeds, one finds that $$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert w-a\rvert = r_n} \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}}\,dw,$$ where $r_n = \sigma$ for $n < 0$, and $r_n = \rho$ for $n\geqslant 0$. Then one uses Cauchy's integral theorem to see that in fact the integral for $c_n$ is independent of $r_n$ [of course we must have $0 < r_n < r$ to have a circle

Comment: in $\Omega$], since in the integral formula for $c_n$, you indeed no longer have the $\frac{1}{w-z}$ which produces a singularity of the integrand in $\Omega$, but $\frac{1}{(w-a)^{n+1}}$, which has no singularity in $\Omega$ anymore.

Comment: I edited in a new suggested proof in the main post, is that correct?, especially the part about beeing able to use a arbitrary radi r in the annulus?

Comment: It is, in fact, the same proof in different words. The "and letting the gate between them go to zero" Would leave you with a path connecting the two circles, but integrated over once in each direction, so these integrals cancel, whence that path can be dropped. The part about using an arbitrary radius is also right, but you must be aware that that only works after the interchange of integration and summation, for which you need the two circles.